# немогу запустить код на Django

Tags: python, django

Я написал код,и запустил. Но мне дали ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python\django\newproject\newproject\settings.py", line 124, in <module>
    BASE_DIR / "static",
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Я так понял, ошибка заключается в одном участке кода, в файле settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Я уже пробовал добавить str, но мне неособо помогало:

```
1.STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR str "static",
]

2.STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR /: str("static",)
]
```

Comment: версия django: 2.0.13

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),]

Comment: Судя по синтаксису `BASE_DIR / "static",` у вас ожидалось, что в `BASE_DIR` будет объект `Path`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что в коде вы как-будто пытаетесь разделить `BASE_DIR` на строку `"static"` и, конечно вылетает ошибка.

Если вы хотите добавить к `BASE_DIR` строку `"static"`, и получить `<ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ BASE_DIR>/static`, то такой код сработает:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR + "/static",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема, решила так:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```